# Which version of Hermes is working with RN 0.63.4

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

I've been trying to install a different version but my app keeps on crashing and when I install the latest version I get this error after a successful build:

```
ReferenceError: Property '_setGlobalConsole' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
[Sun Jan 17 2021 16:45:30.631] ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), js engine: hermes
[Sun Jan 17 2021 16:45:30.640] ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication), js engine: hermes
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Invariant+Violation%3A+Module+AppRegistry+is+not+a+registered+callable+module+(calling+runApplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error when upgrading to `react-native-reanimated v2`, I found out I missed to add `'react-native-reanimated/plugin'` to `babel.config.js` (see [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/#babel-plugin))